# Is $(-y,x)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in $[W^{1,\infty}([0,1]^2)]^2$

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, vector-fields, regularity-theory-of-pdes

in an application I have the following vector field $$\beta(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(-y,x)$$

and I need to check if this lives in the Sobolev space $[W^{1,\infty}([0,1]^2)]^2$

Looking at the first component $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, I should check that:

1. it is in $L^\infty([0,1]^2)$
2. its gradient is in $L^\infty([0,1]^2)$

I think it's not in $L^\infty$, as it blows up at the origin. At the same time, the $L^\infty$ norm doesn't "see" measure zero sets like the origin $(0,0)$, so I'm wondering if it's in $L^\infty$ or not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it really blow up near the origin? You should check your inequalities again.

Comment: Your function is homogeneous of order 0, i.e. $\beta(\lambda X)= \beta(X)$ for all $\lambda>0$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{ 0\}$. It a general fact that then the gradient will be homogeneous of order $-1$ and so will blow up at the origin (so the derivatives are not $L^\infty$).

Comment: I started with $x^2+y^2 \geq y^2$, so  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\frac{1}{y}$, as $y>0$. Then I have $|\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}| \leq y/y=1$ so I don't know how to show it's 0... @NinadMunshi

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks Jose, I'll try do to a more direct computation. Just one thing: so if a component of the gradient blows up at a point, we can still say it's not in $L^\infty$? I was thinking that the $L^\infty$ norm doesn't see points

Comment: If it's $\leq 1$, how is that not the very definition of boundedness? The limit may not exist but we can make statements about the sup of the function.

Comment: Right, but then I wanted to find the limit at $(0,0)$... is it possible? @NinadMunshi

Comment: Why should the limit exist?

Comment: Ah, right... indeed using polars it depends on $\theta$. so it doesn't exist. Thanks

Comment: @NinadMunshi For what concerns $\partial_x$, I have that it is $\frac{-xy}{(x^2+y^2)^(\frac{3}{2})}$. Using polars I have  $\frac{-\rho^2 \sin(2 \theta) }{\rho^3} = - \frac{\sin(2 \theta)}{\rho}$... how can I see it's not bounded? It's still depending on $\theta$.

Comment: In that case it is not bounded, thus it is not $L^\infty$

Comment: Thanks, but why do you say it's not bounded? I mean, in the limit I wrote I have still a dependence on $\theta$... @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 1):

Your function is in $L^\infty ([0,1]^2 ; \mathbb R^2)$ but it is not in $W^{1,\infty}([0,1]^2 ; \mathbb R^2)$. Indeed, for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, $$ \vert \beta(x,y) \vert= \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =1,$$ so $$ \| \beta \|_{L^\infty ([0,1]^2 ; \mathbb R^2)} = \underset{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2}{\mathrm{ess} \, \sup} \vert \beta(x,y) \vert =1.$$

However, you can check that the gradient is not in $L^\infty$. We have that for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, $$ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} =\bigg ( \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac32}}, \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac32}}\bigg ).$$ Hence, $$ \bigg \vert \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} \bigg \vert =\frac1{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac32}} \sqrt{x^2y^2+y^4} = \frac{\vert y \vert}{x^2+y^2}.$$ Approaching $(0,0)$ along the line $x=0$ we find $$ \bigg \vert \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} \bigg \vert = \frac{\vert y \vert}{y^2}=\frac1{\vert y \vert} \to \infty$$ as $y \to 0$.